# Dynamic resizing of the body (LibGDX)

Tags: dynamic, resize, libgdx

I have a circle-shaped dynamic body and I need to resize it during the game (It appears like a point, then it grows to a circle and after that it starts moving). How should I do that? 
I have an idea - it's to use some animation (Circle has the same radius, but due to animation it looks like the circle grows), but I'm not sure if it's right way or not. (Besides I don't know how to realize it)

Comment: Are you using box2D as you are talking about body? Maybe you could have a look into scene2D, it provides the so called `Actions` where you can tell an `Actor` how he should change over time. There are also some tutorials on how to use it with Box2D. However i never tryed it myself, so it is just an advice.

Answer (score 2):

For scaling circle, if you are using sprite just scale it **sprite.setScale(float)**, if your sprite is attached to Box2d Circle-shape then get the Body's shape and set the radius

```
Shape shape = body.getFixture().getShape;
shape.setRadius(radiusValue);
```

and if you are using ShapeRenderer just multiply the points of ShapeRenderer.

Comment: It does not work with spritehelper levelhelper. I am using cocos2d-x v2.2.1. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you are talking about a Box2D body.

It is not possible to change a circle-shaped fixture with Box2D. Box2D is a **rigid** body simulator. What you would have to do is destroy the fixture and replace it with a smaller/bigger version of the circle. But this will cause a lot of problems, since you cannot destroy a fixture when there is still a contact for example.

It would be better to keep the circle the same size and just simulate a change in size with an animation of a texture on top.

If you cannot simulate that, then maybe try the following approach: Have several versions of that circle in different sizes and keep them on top of each other. Implement a ContactFilter which will only cause contacts for the one circle which is currently "active".

Answer (score 2):

Inside any Object class with box2d, I use the following for dynamic resizing:

```
public void resize(float newradius) {
    this.body.destroyFixture(this.fixture); 
    fixtureDef.density = (float) (this.mass/(Math.PI*newradius*newradius)); 
    this.radius = newradius; 

    CircleShape circle = new CircleShape(); 
    circle.setRadius(newradius); 
    this.fixtureDef.shape = circle; 
    circle.dispose(); 

    this.fixture = body.createFixture(fixtureDef); 
    this.fixture.setUserData(this);
}
```

You can also see the following topic: [How to change size after it has been created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24967337/how-to-change-size-after-it-has-been-created)